# How to get the array format to function on x axis labels?

Tags: highcharts

I found this article: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting. It says that I can iterate through an array using the `#each()` function. I have tried using this, but it does not work. Below is a snip example of what I am trying to do:

```
                    "format": " '{#each(years)}",
                    "style": {
                        "fontSize": "12px",
                        "lineHeight": "16px",
                        "color": "#333333",
                        "fontFamily": "roboto",
                        "fontWeight": "normal",
                        "textShadow": false
                    },
                    "enabled": true,
                    "overflow": "allow",
                    "padding": 5
                },
```

`var years = ["20", "21", "22", "23", "24"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware that it might not be obvious from this article but described methods concerns only the **accessibility**. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module

It doesn't have an impact on the visual output of the chart.

Use the formatter callback instead:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qbrftahc/

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
  formatter() {
    return years[this.x]
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter